# Wrap a word in python

Tags: python

I want to wrap the string below:

```
string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

With the max width as **4**, for instance I want this output:

[image: Output that I want]

I created this function:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    i = max_width
    while True:
        string = string[:i] + '\n' + string[i+1:]
        if i >= len(string):
            break
    return string

if __name__=='__main__':
    string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ'
    print(wrap(string, 4))
```

But the outputs was:

[image: My Output]

May you help me, please?

Comment: Help us help you - paste your code as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: Consider using the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/textwrap.html) in the standard library.

Comment: Not exact duplicate, but this should help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/2422776

Comment: In general when learning to code, you want to master the art of debugging. In this case, where you have a loop, you want to see what is happening in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ'

for i in range(0, len(string), 4):
    print(string[i:i+4])
```

Output

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return '\n'.join(string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0,len(string),max_width))
```

Comment: Or they could use the built in textwrap module and call textwrap.wrap()

Comment: True, but based on the question I thought that g3rno was trying to create their own wrap function.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `i+1` with `i` like this:

```py
string = string[:i] + "\n" + string[i:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try with regular expression:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return '\n'.join(re.findall(f'.{{1,{max_width}}}',string))
```